# Android Camera connected to device, Stop launching gallery

Tags: android, camera, gallery, media

When i connect a Digital camera to the android device with USB, After camera is mounted, immediately android is Launching a galley. I need to stop that. Does any one know how to stop launching gallery. When digital camera is connected.

Comment: which device you are using ?

Comment: @Lucifer I am using panda board, I am running my custom rom in it. So when i connect camera to it it launches gallery application.